# Can this criterion to indicate the randomness some numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, random-functions

John Derbyshire in his book [PRIME OBSESSION](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Nombres/Derbyshire%20-%20Prime%20Obsession%20-%20Bernhard%20Riemann%20and%20the%20Greatest%20Unsolved%20Problem%20in%20MathematicsAAA.pdf) says on page 366:
CHAPTER 3
10.

> "Here is an example of e turning up unexpectedly. Select **a random number**
>   between **0 and 1**. Now **select another** and add it to the first. Keep
>   doing this, **piling on random numbers**.
>   How many **random numbers**, **on average**, do you need to make the **total greater than 1**?
>    Answer: **2.71828….**"

**Question**: Is the opposite of the above statement true? or Can we have the same result e=2.71828... with non-random numbers in (0, 1)?

Explanation:

> Select a **number** between 0 and 1. Now **select another** and add it to the first. Keep doing this, **piling on numbers**.
>   If we find that, **on average**, we need  **2.71828…**. numbers to make the **total greater than 1**? Are these **numbers random**? -Where: (Random numbers are numbers that occur in a sequence such that two conditions are met: (1) the values are uniformly distributed over a defined interval or set, and (2) it is impossible to predict future values based on past or present ones. https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/random-numbers)

Analytically: If we have a set of numbers D = {d<sub>1</sub>,d<sub>2</sub>,d<sub>3</sub>,...,d<sub>n</sub>} and we know nothing for d<sub>k</sub> except that it belongs in space (0,1), k=1,2,3,..,n and we take the subsets  {d<sub>1</sub>,d<sub>2</sub>,...,d<sub>x1</sub>}, {d<sub>x1+1</sub>,d<sub>x1+2</sub>,...,d<sub>x2</sub>},.., {d<sub>xj+1</sub>,d<sub>xj+2</sub>,...,d<sub>xn</sub>=d<sub>n</sub>}, such that: x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>,..,x<sub>n</sub> are the minimum number of consecutive elements of set D
required that their sum be greater than 1. ie d<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>2</sub> + d<sub>3</sub> +...+ d<sub>x1</sub> > 1, d<sub>x1+1</sub> + d<sub>x1+2</sub>  +...+ d<sub>x2</sub> > 1, ...

Now we define the sequence a(1) = x<sub>1</sub>, 
 a(2)  = x<sub>2</sub>,..., a(n) = x<sub>n</sub>.

Finally we find the $\lim \frac{a(1) + ... + a(n)}{n}$, n = 1,2,3,4,...

If we find it and is equal to $e = 2.718281828459045235360287471....$,

Can we claim that the elements of set D are random numbers? But if limit differs e then they are not random numbers?

Comment: Is your $a(n)$ supposed to be $a(m)$? Are you using some actual definition of randomness? Can you write your code so it's readable, and explain what it means?

Comment: No. Depending on **m** will require larger or smaller samples of the sequence b(k) to stabilize the convergence of (a(1) + ... + a(n)) / n, n=1,2,3,4,...

Comment: The sequence b(k)={1,8,15,22,29,36,...} will never reach the e limit.                {
s=0;i=0;s1=0;k=0;m=100;
forstep(nn=1,100000000,7,
         n=nn;
         d=n%m;s1+=d;k++;
         if(s1>=m,
            s+=k;i++;s1=0;k=0;
           )
        )
;print1(s/i*1.0)      
}  2.8571430000000000000000000000000000000
that is rational number.

Comment: From a probablist's perspective, every time you say the word "randomly" you have to specify the distribution.

Comment: It'd be extremely helpful if you'd format your code in a reasonable way, with line breaks in reasonable places.  Use the `{ }` button to get a nice monospaced code block.  As @GerryMyerson says, it's nearly impossible to read as it stands.  (If you'd care to give your variables meaningful names, that would be very helpful too.)

Comment: To add to @NateEldredge 's comment:  From a probabilist's perspective, every time you say the phrase "I base my idea on the fact that the probability of XXXX, is", the next word should not be $e$. (Or anything else greater than $1$).

Comment: My idea based in fact, that we need to select on average e random numbers between 0 and 1, to make their sum greater than 1. The program implements and generalizes this property.

Comment: You could clarify: "least number of successive $b(k)$ numbers mod $m$ *starting from $k=1$*".

Comment: if b(k)=prime(k) and m=100 then b(k)={2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,...} for k=1,2,3,4,...
So a(n)={9, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6,...} n=1,2,3,4,5,...
a(1)=9 because 9 "prime numbers mod 100" are required so that the sum is >= 100 (2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19+23 = 100).
a(2)=4 because the next 4 "prime numbers mod 100"  29+31+37+41 = 138 >= 100.and I conjecture that the limit (a(1) + ... + a(n))/n exists and is equal to e = 2.718281828459045235360287471.... ie (9+4+3+2+ 2+2+2+3+6+3+2+...+a(n))/(11 or ...n) --> e.

Comment: Try this code to find a(n): {

s1=0; k=0; m=100;

forprime(n=2,2000 ,

  d=n%m;

  s1+=d; k++;

  if(s1>=m,

    print1(k", ");

    s1=0; k=0;

)

)}

Comment: Is it $a(m)$ since you want something $\pmod m$ ? There is something wrong in your variables. Also you want to add successive terms starting from $b(1)$ ?

Comment: No, m=100 means 2%100+3%100+5%100+7%100+11%100+13%100+17%100+19%100+23%100 = 100>=100=m. So a(1)=9. If we beginning in area nn ->100000 to 100420 with m=1000 we have the prime numbers: 100003,100019,100043, 100049,100057,100069,100103,100109, 100129,100151, 100153,100169,100183,100189,100193,100207,100213,100237,..,100417. So 100003%1000=3, 100019%1000=19,100043%m=43,100049%m=49, 100057%m,100069%m, 100103%m,100109%m,100129%m,100151%m,100153%m,100169%m=169 and sum is 3+19+43+49+57+69+103+109+129+151+153+169=1054>=1000 =m. Now a(1)=12, same the next 6 primes gives sum 1222>=1000=m and a(2)=6..

Comment: Please, Dimitris, go to the Help menu for some tips on formatting mathematics on this site. Learn how to make >= look like $\ge$, and so on, to make your math less painful to read.

Comment: Sorry for my amateurism and for my English. I have some difficulties with the google translator. I have also stated that I am an amateur "mathematician". I will try to simplify to make it more understandable. Later I will generalize it.

Comment: I still can't get past the definition of $a(n)$. In the current version, it doesn't seem to depend on $n$ at all. $a(73)$ is "the least number of successive prime numbers modulo 100 required such that their sum is at least 100," and so is $a(455)$ and $a(65536)$ and so on.

Comment: OK, now that I've read the entry at oeis, I finally understand the question (I edited in a link to make it easier for others). But I still don't see why the conjecture implies the primes are distributed randomly, and I still don't see any definition of the phrase "distributed randomly".

Comment: FWIW, the definition (which isn't even clearly stated on OEIS, disappointingly) appears to be as follows. Let $M=100$ and $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. Then $a(0) = 0$, and $a(n+1)$ is minimal $a$ such that $M \leq \sum_{i=1}^a p_{a(1) + \dots + a(n) + i} \% M$, where $k \% M$ denotes the remainder (in $[0,M-1]$, I presume) when dividing $k$ by $M$.

Comment: Because I can not prove it, I made a simple program in (PARI) that implements the above and and I did experiments with numerical data. With setrand(3) we have:
D={0.90617260370907361..., 0.4433496084470082..., 0.0261813442920161469..., 0.697496143345466..., 0.2045655413402841..., 0.3020591339197748...,...}{
s1=0.0; k=0;i=0;s=0;d=0.0;setrand(3);
for(nn=1, 10^7,
             d=random(.1);
              s1+=d; k++;
              if(s1>1,
                 s+=k;i++;
                 s1=0.0; k=0;
               )
           )
;print1(s/i*1.0)
}   The result 2.71860775733052265511222 ~ e.

Comment: You have edited your question in such a way that many of the replies no longer make any sense. It's clear from the context that Derbyshire uses "random" to mean "independent, uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$". You wanted to apply "random" to primes, but there are no primes between 0 and 1, so you were doomed before you started. If you don't pay attention to definitions, you are condemned to forever writing unintelligible nonsense.

Comment: Assuming that you meant essentially what Derbyshire wrote (even though your formulas don't agree with that), I'll make the trivial observation that there is a sequence, using only the numbers $2/5$ and $3/5$, for which Derbyshire's limit is $e$. The sequence consists of blocks of either $3$ consecutive $2/5$s or 2 consecutive $3/5$s. Each such block is just enough to produce a total $>1$. The average lengths of these blocks can be made to approach $e$ by adjusting the numbers of the two sorts of blocks appropriately. And of course such a sequence is not random.

Comment: Forgot prime numbers The question is general (perhaps I should put it as a new question to become more understandable)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you have understand what I mean. I am interested in the counter-example you give me, because it will help me to understand if the reverse of the above statement is true or not. This try to understand but with my poor English I can not express it well. But what do you mean "by adjusting the numbers of the two sorts of blocks appropriately". Can you give me an example how to do it? Why (even though your formulas don't agree with that)?

Comment: More analytically I can not expres what I want to say, because my English does not help me.
If someone has understood my question, give me a reply with a yes or no (if the question has a response). If my question is silly please delete the "article"

Comment: If you have a counter-example. ie a set of non random numbers in space (0,1)  that satisfy the above conditions and give result e. Please give it to me.

Comment: Κωνσταντίνε ευχαριστώ για την βοήθεια. Δεν είμαι "επαγγελματίας" μαθηματικός, οπότε μάλλον δεν είμαι πάντα αυστηρός με τις διατυπώσεις. 
Αν βάλεις και τα χάλια Αγγλικά χάος!!!
Παρ' όλα αυτά θέλω μερικές ιδέες μου, να τις μοιράζομαι για να μαθαίνω. Κάποιες φαίνονται καλές και άλλες τετριμμένες, κάποιες άλλες ανόητες! 
Εδώ, διαβάζοντας την "Εμμονή με τους Πρώτους" και φτάνοντας στο σημείο που περιγράφω στην ερώτηση, μου ήρθε η ιδέα να αντιστρέψω το παραπάνω λήμμα.

Comment: Βασικά ρωτώ αν για το αποτέλεσμα "e=2.71828..." ισχύει το "ικανή και αναγκαία συνθήκη", "εάν και μόνο εάν". 
Δηλαδή, για ένα σύνολο αριθμών στο ανοιχτό διάστημα (0,1), για τους οποίους διαπιστώνουμε, ότι χρειαζόμαστε κατά μέσο όρο 2.71828... από αυτούς, 
για να ξεπεράσει το άθροισμά τους το 1, μπορούμε να συμπεράνουμε ότι είναι τυχαίοι. Όπως γενικά ορίζεται η τυχαιότητα. 
Αλλιώς θα πρέπει να υπάρχουν σύνολα όχι τυχαίων αριθμών, που να ικανοποιούν τις παραπάνω συνθήκες. Οπότε η συνθήκη θα είναι μόνο "ικανή".

Comment: Δηλαδή αν οι αριθμοί είναι τυχαίοι, μας δίνουν το αποτέλεσμα e=2.71828... αλλά δεν χρειάζεται να είναι κατ' "ανάγκη" τυχαίοι. Έχω τον λόγο μου που θέλω την επιβεβαίωση ή όχι του δικού μου ισχυρισμού. Αν ισχύει, θα μπορούσα να δημιουργήσω σύνολα αριθμών στο (0,1) και να έχω τουλάχιστον μια ένδειξη της τυχαιότητάς τους. Πχ συναρτήσεις f τέτοιες ώστε f(prime(n)) να δίνουν τιμές στο (0,1) οπότε ίσως είχα μια ένδειξη, της τυχαιότητας των πρώτων αριθμών

Comment: Dimitris, this isn't going well. Part of the problem is that "randomness" isn't actually a well-defined property we can attribute to individual sequences of numbers, as in saying "this sequence is random, but that sequence is not". For example, if you asked a bunch of mathematicians to list the sequence of primes, you will consistently get the same result; where's the randomness of that? The theory of probability that mathematicians have developed over generations has to be more subtle than that. Moreover, MO isn't designed to give high-level tutorials about this -- please ask somewhere else.

Comment: Dear Todd, I know all that you say. I did a simple question, I never asked "to take high-level tutorials about this". (Part of the problem is that "randomness" isn't actually a well-defined property we can attribute to individual sequences of numbers, as in saying "this sequence is random, but that sequence is not".)
I finally, this is I want to do, to give a clear definition of randomness.

Comment: Example for a sequence b(k) of integer numbers. Definition: Can we say, that the terms of this sequence b(k) are random or randomly distributed, if and only if ( iff ) there is an appropriate function f such that f(b(k)) belongs to (0,1) and the $\lim \frac{a(1) + ... + a(n)}{n}$, n = 1,2,3, 4,...  is e = 2.7182. ..Where, a(n)  defined above analytically. (If I have given, understandably, the definition of a(n)). And I ask again why this definition does not stand well? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Again: MO cannot be a back-and-forth discussion board for speculations. Please don't be insulted, but your proposed definition is hopelessly vague and ill-formulated. Let me say, since you seem to be an amateur hoping one day to prove RH: one could very easily waste a life chasing chimeras this way. The respect you should have for this problem is analogous to the respect you'd have for a mountain 100 times as high as Everest. One can't say it's absolutely impossible to climb that mountain, but realistically, you need extraordinarily advanced tools and techniques. Thinking otherwise is madness.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. Those who deal with mathematics from hobby do not waste their lives, but they find it fun. Because maths are fun. I like the way for the goal. The final goal I leave it to those who know mathematics very well. I believe, however, that from one city to another there are infinite and complex routes, but there is always an easy and simple one that could be used and for small children, as long as it is discovered.

Comment: My decency, from my home and my parents for 63 years has taught me to respect andnot offend anyone. I believe that knowledge of mathematics is a privilege of all. But finally did not you give me a reply why my definition is vague?
As long as you give me the right, i will say my opinion on math and if you do not like it you can delete it. I can say sometime and something useful.
Finally, I have been a climber in mountains  for the last 40 years.

Comment: According to your proposed definition, the sequence 1, 2, 3, ... would be "random". The only other thing I'll say is that I'm glad you find math fulfilling, but please bear in mind MO is not a discussion board, and that the time of others is precious to them. That is all.

Answer (score 3):

I find several problems with this.

The first problem is that you do not have a clear definition for the a(j) values.  In particular, after reading your code, it seems a(2) depends not only on the sequence, but on the value of a(1).  In particular, if a(1) is k, then a(2) is not also k, as might be expected, it is a value which depends on the sum of b(i) starting not from I= 2, but from i=k+1.

Why is this a problem? Suppose I rewrite the sequence and replace b(2) through b(k) with the same number which is near their average (and I do something similar with b(k+2) to b(k+a(2)), and so on).  If I run your program on this sequence, I get the same output. So this modified and often constant sequence and bounded by m sequence will measure just as random as your original sequence, even though it has long predictable runs. I'm not sure you are ready for that kind of random.

Second is that (as far as I can see) you are picking a single modulus m to determine this test of randomness.  There may be a wealth of structure that is happening with the modified sequence b(k)-(b(k) mod m), or a wealth of randomness, but your test ignores that, and I am not seeing you vary m.

Third problem is that you are not guaranteed if you vary m that a random sequence will produce the same limit with your process. What if you get four different limits with four different values of m?  How do you handle that?

A fourth problem is that many random sequences are bounded, and your process will not give the signaling value of e if your modulus m is too large.

A fifth problem is that the primes are not that random, and that this process will reveal something, but it is not clear that that something has to do with randomness or with primes.

If you are interested in such things, you might consider equidistribution or uniform distribution results for sequences.  I don't know the literature, but I believe related results in number theory are by H. Weyl.  Perhaps others here can provide a relevant reference.

Gerhard "57 Isn't A Random Prime" Paseman, 2018.08.07.

Comment: Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Yes it is more understandable.  The link to OEIS helps, and confirms my understanding.  I keep my answer the same: there are problems with the process.  I also think that for m=100 and b(i) the primes, computation will show your limit is not e, and possibly is near 2.704 as mentioned in the OEIS.  Gerhard "And Primes Still Aren't Random" Paseman, 2018.08.07.

Comment: My conjecture  either is correct or not, does that mean that the method is correct and reveals it (that isn't random distributed if limit is 2.704....)? And how many prime numbers will be used to stabilize the limit. If instead of 100 we choose 1000 this will give us better accuracy but will need a larger sample of prime numbers? Finally if the limit is not e can assume that the prime numbers hide some pattern?

Comment: I think the conjecture is not correct. I think the method you propose does not detect randomness.  I think the primes are also not random.  I do not see how to modify the process or suggest a change that would produce something that detected randomness reliably.  Gerhard "Consider Other Statistical Randomness Tests" Paseman, 2018.08.07.

Comment: The problem with the limit e or not when the prime numbers are used in the random number generator position, is that they are placed in ascending order (2,3,5,7,11,13,..), as opposed to random numbers. So the method does not work well in small samples. (Unless we find a smarter way of using the prime numbers in the above, not necessarily in the order).Else will need much more samples to reveal exactly where the limit is.

Comment: That's why I still believe that the limit will eventually converge to e. Because the act shows that prime numbers behave in a random fashion. That I understand, will it be the conclusion if the Riemann Hypothesis true?

Comment: If the above limit after a large sample of prime numbers stabilized  close to 2.704 ... My above work has not achieved its goal? ie this give another one indication that the prime numbers are not randomly distributed?

Comment: In my opinion, no.  Even if you vary m and manage to get the same limit, I don't think it resolves the question of randomness either way.  Gerhard "Unless You Change Randomness Itself" Paseman, 2018.08.09.

Comment: Although you might find it in pop science accounts, mathematically it's a bad idea to refer to a sequence of numbers generated by a definite rule or algorithm (such as the prime numbers, or the digits of $\pi$) as "random". There are precise probabilistic concepts (such as normality of a number) which encapsulate behavior generally expected of "random sequences" (such as a hypothetical infinite stream of fair coin flips), but you need to be precise. (Elsewhere one speaks of "algorithmically random sequences", but that doesn't apply here.)